# Django widget attrs={'type':'date'} not working

Tags: django, forms, date, widget

It should be so simple. I'm following all the rules and all the answers from previous questions but it still won't happen. I have a Bottle model, that has it's own inline formset form to it's parent Wine. The date on which I bought the bottle, should show up as a standard date picker. I cannot for the life of my figure out where it goes wrong. The input type should change from "text" to "date", but it won't.

I'm using crispy forms and bootstrap 5, but disabling those also does nothing.

My models (only relevant models shown):

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Wine(models.Model):
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    alcohol = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    grape = models.ManyToManyField(Grape)
    colour = models.ForeignKey(Colour, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    wine_type = models.ForeignKey(WineType, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    wishlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_bottles(self):
        a = []
        for bottle in self.Bottle.all():
            a.append((bottle.date_bought))

        return a

    def available_bottle(self):
        number = self.Bottle.filter(available=True).count()
        return number


class Bottle(models.Model):
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, related_name='Bottle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_bought = models.DateField(null=True)
    bottleprice = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    #notes = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    drank_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_bought)
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.drank_on is not None:
            self.available=False

        super(Bottle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import WineForm, BottleForm
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Wine, Bottle, WineType, Country


def wine_list(request):
    wines = Wine.objects.order_by('name')
    context = {
        'wines': wines,
        # 'available_bottles': Bottle.objects.filter(available=True).count()
    }
    return render(request, 'winedb/wine_list.html', context)

def wine_detail(request, pk):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, id=pk)
    bottles = wine.Bottle.all()
    context = {'wine': wine,
    'bottles': bottles}
    return render(request, 'winedb/wine_detail.html', context)


def add_new_bottle(request, pk):
    WineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Wine, Bottle, fields=('date_bought', 'bottleprice', 'available', 'drank_on'))
    wine = Wine.objects.get(id=pk)
    formset = WineFormSet(instance=wine)
    # form = BottleForm(initial={'wine':wine})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BottleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            wine = form.save(commit=False)
            wine.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'winedb/bottle_form.html', context)

def add_new_wine(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WineForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            wine = form.save(commit=False)
            wine.save()
            return redirect('wine_detail', id=wine.pk)
    else:
        form = WineForm()
    return render(request, 'winedb/wine_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

The form:

```
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Wine, Bottle
    class WineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Wine
        fields = ('producer', 'name', 'year', 'alcohol', 'grape', 'colour', 'wine_type', 'notes', 'wishlist')

class BottleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_bought = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Bottle
        fields = ('wine', 'date_bought', 'bottleprice', 'available', 'drank_on') 

        widgets= {
            'date_bought': forms.DateInput(
                attrs={'type':'date'}), 
        }
```

And the template:

```
{% extends 'winedb/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New Bottle</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {% for form in formset%}
            {{ form }}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried literally anything. From changing the format, to changing the language from US to UK in my settings and using custom widgets like:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Found the error, I should have added to attrs to the field in my view:

```
def add_new_bottle(request, pk):
    WineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Wine, Bottle, 
        fields=('date_bought', 'bottleprice', 'available', 'drank_on'), 
        widgets= {
            'date_bought': forms.DateInput(
                attrs={'type':'date'}), 
        })
```